# Contact Form mailer.php returns a blank page

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha, contact-form

The contact form was working fine until I tried to add reCAPTCHA. I have managed to make reCAPTCHA appear, have the recaptchalib , and the mailer.php which is the page displaying a blank page. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Here is the mailer.php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // check reCAPTCHA information
    require_once('recaptchalib.php');

    $privatekey = "privatekey";
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

    // if CAPTCHA is correctly entered!                        
    if ($resp->is_valid) {
        // great success!    
        $myemail = "operations@socialmarketing.com";

        /* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
        $name = $_POST['inputName'];
        $email = $_POST['inputEmail'];
        $subject = $_POST['inputSubject'];
        $message = $_POST['inputMessage'];

        /* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */

        $subject = "Message From LGBT campaign Contact Form";

        $message = "

        China LGBT Contact Form

        Name: $name
        Email: $email

        Message:
        $message

        ";

        /* Send the message using mail() function */
        mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

        /* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
        header('Location: successPage.html#contact');

    } else {
       // alert the captcha is not correct

    }
}?>
```

Here is my HTML page, which I have made a .php page

```
<div class="marketing">
<div class="intro" id="contact">
  <h1>Contact Us</h1>
  <p>If you would like to stay informed about our progress or would like to help with the campaign, please fill out this form to send us an email.</p>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form name="contactform" id="contactform" action="mailer.php" class="form-horizontal" role="form"  method="POST">


      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputName" placeholder="Your Name">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Your Email">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="inputMessage" placeholder="Your message..."></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
        <p>Prove you are not a spambot</p>
        <?php require_once('recaptchalib.php');
            $publickey = "publickey";
            echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
          ?>

    </div>
  </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help with this would be hugely appreciated guys.

Thanks a bunch

*SOLUTION*

```
<form name="contactform" id="contactform" action="mailer.php" class="form-horizontal" role="form"  method="post">


      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputName" placeholder="Your Name">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Your Email">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="inputMessage" placeholder="Your message..."></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
        <p>Prove you are not a spambot</p>
        <?php require_once('recaptchalib.php');
            $publickey = "6Le0ff0SAAAAAOCeQiOcGUwQEfXERDyNJ";
            echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
          ?>

    </div>
  </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send Message" name="submit">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

<?php 

 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // check reCAPTCHA information
    require_once('recaptchalib.php');

    $privatekey = "6Le0ff0SAAAALTDn4IkqNSN5F0AU2Ezhvf";
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

    // if CAPTCHA is correctly entered!                        
    if ($resp->is_valid) {
        // great success!    
        $myemail = "kenm@socialmarketing.com";


        /* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
        $name = $_POST['inputName'];
        $email = $_POST['inputEmail'];
        $subject = "Message From LGBT campaign Contact Form";
        $message = $_POST['inputMessage'];
        $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        /* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */

        $message = "

        China LGBT Contact Form

        Name: $name
        Email: $email

        Message:
        $message

        ";

        /* Send the message using mail() function */
        mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

        /* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
        header('Location: successPage.html#contact');

    } else {

       // alert the captcha is not correct
      echo "captcha did not match!";
      exit;

    }
}?>
```

Comment: Could be a 500 error. Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: I would start by checking on the browser (via dev tools) that the correct parameters are being sent in the request, specially `$_POST['submit']`

Comment: You don't have a named form element called `submit` and everything inside that conditional statement, will not fire up. You're relying solely on `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>` which won't work. It needs to be named. I.e.: `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Send Message</button>`

Comment: So whenever I added <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Send Message</button>, once I tried to submit the form, it wouldn't go anywhere. I did add the code mentioned by EternalHour bellow.  Is there anything wrong in the mailer.php?

Comment: That should have worked. Ok, use this then `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit" name="submit">` @KenRyan consult my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26853661/1415724

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your button to this:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send Message" name="submit">
```

POST is looking for a named attribute called `submit`.

which based on your conditional statement, and nothing will execute inside it because of it:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {...}
```

You also don't have a *named* form element to go with `$subject = $_POST['inputSubject'];`

Either add one:

```
Subject:<input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputSubject" placeholder="Subject">
```

or simply test with:

```
$subject = "Form submitted";
```

You should make sure that all fields are filled. If the subject is left empty or any other, you may not receive mail because of it, especially the Email field.

Another reason may be because you do not have proper headers, including a `From:`

Visit the PHP.net website on mail:

- **http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php**

Example `From:` header from the website:

```
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

and modifying `mail($myemail, $subject, $message);`
to `mail($myemail, $subject, $message, $headers);`

Quoting them:

> Note:
>
> When sending mail, the mail must contain a From header. This can be set with the additional_headers parameter, or a default can be set in php.ini.
>
> Failing to do this will result in an error message similar to Warning: mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing. The From header sets also Return-Path under Windows.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Let me give this a shot! :)

Comment: @KenRyan Ok. However, do reload my answer, I have added additional and important information in regards to `From:` and extra header information.

Comment: that fixed it! Just had to add the rest of the else statement to `else {
           // alert the captcha is not correct
     // alert the captcha is not correct
    echo "captcha did not match!";
    exit;` so it goes somewhere when captcha is not correct. Thank you very much @Fred -ii-

Comment: @KenRyan You're quite welcome Ken, glad to have been of help, *cheers*

Comment: @KenRyan Oh, and thanks for the added edit to your question, I upvoted too, *cheers* Ken.

Comment: @KenRyan So my answer helped you, yet no appreciation? Nice. +1 to Fred for the detailed answer.

Comment: @EternalHour Sorry about that! Thought I had done it :) THanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a blank page, it's because something is failing and not showing an error. I'd start by making sure that error reporting is enabled in your PHP script. Add this to the top of mailer.php.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

You also need to add some sort of message here.

```
} else {

    // alert the captcha is not correct
    echo "captcha did not match!";
    exit;

}
```

Also as mentioned, check your error log.

Comment: I added the line you mentioned as well as content in the else statement. It still won't work though.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by changing

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
```

to

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">
```

This should submit your form to mailer.php. From that point on it should work.